# Creating aliases for Python packages?

Tags: python, package

I have a directory, let's call it `Storage` full of packages with unwieldy names like `mypackage-xxyyzzww`, and of course `Storage` is on my `PYTHONPATH`. Since packages have long unmemorable names, all of the packages are symlinked to friendlier names, such as `mypackage`.

Now, I don't want to rely on file system symbolic links to do this, instead I tried mucking around with `sys.path` and `sys.modules`. Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
import imp
imp.load_package('mypackage', 'Storage/mypackage-xxyyzzww')
```

How bad is it to do things this way, and is there a chance this will break in the future? One funny thing is that there's even no mention of `imp.load_package` function in the docs.

EDIT: besides not relying on symbolic links, I can't use `PYTHONPATH` variable anymore.

Comment: How about just choosing shorter named?

Comment: If it ever breaks I suppose you could replace it with `load_source` +/ `load_binary`, which are documented.

Comment: @delnan: Good point.  An ounce of prevention worth a pound of hideous hacking around trying to resolve things.  Fixing the names seems to simple.  And yet...

Comment: This is ugly, and will lea to no end of headaches--why aren't you naming the packages in the standard way?  If you want separate versions of packages, then put them in different directories ("xyz/package") and add the version to the search path (`sys.path.add('xyz')`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[importlib](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/importlib.html?highlight=__loader__#example) may be more appropriate, as it uses/implements the [PEP302](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/) mechanism.

Follow the DictImporter example, but override `find_module` to find the real filename and store it in the dict, then override `load_module` to get the code from the found file.

You shouldn't need to use sys.path once you've created your Storage module

```
#from importlib import abc
import imp
import os
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

dprint = logging.debug


class MyImporter(object):
    def __init__(self,path):
        self.path=path
        self.names = {}

    def find_module(self,fullname,path=None):
        dprint("find_module({fullname},{path})".format(**locals()))
        ml = imp.find_module(fullname,path)
        dprint(repr(ml))
        raise ImportError


    def load_module(self,fullname):
        dprint("load_module({fullname})".format(**locals()))
        return imp.load_module(fullname)
        raise ImportError


def load_storage( path, modname=None ):
    if modname is None:
        modname = os.path.basename(path)

    mod = imp.new_module(modname)
    sys.modules[modname] = mod
    assert mod.__name__== modname
    mod.__path__=[path]
    #sys.meta_path.append(MyImporter(path))
    mod.__loader__= MyImporter(path)
    return mod

if __name__=="__main__":
    load_storage("arbitrary-path-to-code/Storage")

    from Storage import plain
    from Storage import mypkg
```

Then when you `import Storage.mypackage`, python will immediately use your importer without bothering to look on `sys.path`

That doesn't work.  The code above does work to import ordinary modules under Storage without requiring Storage to be on sys.path, but both 3.1 and 2.6 seem to ignore the **loader** attribute mentioned in PEP302.
If I uncomment the sys.meta_path line, 3.1 dies with StackOverflow, and 2.6 dies with ImportError. hmmm... I'm out of time now, but may look at it later.

Comment: oops. importlib is new in python 3.1

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using `imp`, you can assign different names to imported modules.

```
import mypackage_xxyyzzww as mypackage
```

If you then create a `__init__.py` file inside of `Storage`, you can add several of the above lines to make importing easier.

**Storage/__init__.py**:

```
import mypackage_xxyyzzww as mypackage
import otherpackage_xxyyzzww as otherpackage
```

**Interpreter:**

```
>>> from Storage import mypackage, otherpackage
```

Comment: "mypackage-xxyyzzww" is not a valid package name.

Comment: Ouch, the problem is not the ugliness of the names - you are using ilegal package names!

Comment: This still doesn't work; you won't be able to `import Storage.mypackage`.

Comment: @Garret Hyde: sorry, the comment was meant to ryidle, your solution is correct, he is the one using ilegal module names.

Comment: If you use the `__init__.py` example, you have to use `from Storage import mypackage`.

Comment: Yes, which means it breaks basic Python import syntax.

Comment: This approach _does_ allow `import Storage.mypackage`. Tested on python 2.4, 2.6 and 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Packages are just entries in the namespace. You should not name your path components with anything that is not a legal python variable name.

Comment: I forgot to mention one thing: I can't use PYTHONPATH variable anymore, so I don't hinkg that would work. Will update the question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: `import a.b` will throw an error if `a/b/__init__.py` doesn't exist, even if `a/__init__.py` sets `b` to something.